# Combining or adding to array with common value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I've got 2 object arrays. I need to add one of the object values to the second array where the names match. What is the most efficient way of doing this with the least amount of code?

```
firstArray = [
              {name: "Henry", balance: 2176.90, Age: 26},
              {name: "Jon", balance: 122.10, Age: 31},
              {name: "Dave", balance: 258.23, Age: 42},
              {name: "Tom", balance: 591.00, Age: 19},
              {name: "Mary", balance: 12.54, Age: 56},
              {name: "Rick", balance: 5287.25, Age: 29},
              {name: "Jane", balance: 6527.20, Age: 24}
           ]

secondArray = [
              {user: "Henry", city: "New York", dept: "Sales"},
              {user: "Vanessa", city: "New York", dept: "Sales"},
              {user: "Susan", city: "Dallas", dept: "Marketing"},
              {user: "Jon", city: "New York", dept: "Management"},
              {user: "Dave", city: "Dallas", dept: "Marketing"}
              {user: "Jay", city: "Spokane", dept: "IT"}
           ]

secondArray = [
              {user: "Henry", city: "New York", dept: "Sales", balance: 2176.90},
              {user: "Vanessa", city: "New York", dept: "Sales", balance: "N/A"},
              {user: "Susan", city: "Dallas", dept: "Marketing", balance: "N/A"},
              {user: "Jon", city: "New York", dept: "Management", balance: 122.10},
              {user: "Dave", city: "Dallas", dept: "Marketing", balance: 258.23}
              {user: "Jay", city: "Spokane", dept: "IT", balance: 591.00}
           ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop over the arrays, there is no more efficient way to handle this.

```
for (var key in firstArray) {
    var obj = firstArray[key];
    for (var key2 in secondArray) {
        obj2 = secondArray[key2];
        if (obj['user'] == obj2['user']){
            //merge stuff here
            secondArray[key2]['balance']=obj['balance'];
            break; //once we found the equal names we can skip the rest.
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: What about by using jquery?

Comment: Same, you can use a $.each loop but the general structure stays the same.